# Showing a confirmation box in Mvc with entity freamwork

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am new to Mvc with entity framework.I have a task to keep an confirmation box in C# code part ..that if i enter the existing data then it will show that confirmation box that data is already exist ..but click on yes  'll continue.but i didn't understand how to wqrite..please help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask - please refer to this when asking a question on StackOverflow

Comment: Could we please be a bit nicer to new users??

http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9953/could-we-please-be-a-bit-nicer-to-new-users

Answer (score 2):

Try [jQuery Dialog](https://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-confirmation). It's pretty easy and very customizable. You can even make it display a partial view in your MVC project, so you design the view the way you want. Here is a sample code from their website:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Dialog - Modal confirmation</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#dialog-confirm" ).dialog({
      resizable: false,
      height:140,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Delete all items": function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="dialog-confirm" title="Empty the recycle bin?">
  <p><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-alert" style="float:left; margin:0 7px 20px 0;"></span>These items will be permanently deleted and cannot be recovered. Are you sure?</p>
</div>
<p>Sed vel diam id libero <a href="http://example.com">rutrum convallis</a>. Donec aliquet leo vel magna. Phasellus rhoncus faucibus ante. Etiam bibendum, enim faucibus aliquet rhoncus, arcu felis ultricies neque, sit amet auctor elit eros a lectus.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't write code in javascript..i have to write in .cs file.and have to catch that true and false.

Comment: @user3423378 To show a confirmation box, there is no way other than JavaScript or some plug-in (Java Applet, Silverlight, flash, etc). If you want to do it in MVC, you will have to make it a separate page.

Answer (score 0):

```
Employee emp = Entities.TableName.FirstOrDefault(rec => rec.LoginID == LoginID);
if (emp == null)
{
    dbResult = true;
}
```

Like this you have to check in controller... you should handle this result using Jquery model popup in view....

Better you learn what is MVC and how its working from

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/introduction/getting-started

Because Here in MVC there is no code behind and all.. Model (classes) View (HTML) Controller(C# coding like business layer)

Comment: i did upto this one but .i want a warning or a confirmation box that this id is already exists

Comment: for this requirement you should use the webApi or WCF and call this update through ajax method(jquery).... parse the responce and show the result.. for more deatils gothrough this site http://www.asp.net/web-api..